# Stuck with Angular-UI TinyMce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

I'm trying to use the Angular-UI TinyMCE directive in my Angular app.

What happens is, I query an endpoint, it returns an array of objects. I have a function that then converts that to a long string with HTML tags in it. Then that data is set to a `$scope.tinymceModel`

This all works fine. I can `console.log($scope.tinymceModel)` and its the proper data.

The problem is the HTML parse function needs to run after the endpoint query is returned. So I've called the function inside the `.success()` callback. For some reason when I set the `$scope.tinymceModel` inside of the callback the TinyMCE directive ignores it. Even if I make it `$scope.tinymceModel = 'test'` but if I place `$scope.tinymceModel = 'test'` outside of the callback it shows up in tinymce just fine.

This tells me that for some reason when the TinyMCE directive is loaded it needs the `tinymceModel` to already be populated with data. I'm not sure how I get around this.

This also tells me that I may have another problem after this. The next task with TinyMCE is the user can then edit the text, click a button and the app will send a POST with the updated info inside `tinymceModel` If this was a regular text box it would be simple because of the data-binding. However it seems TinyMCE doesn't play well with databinding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!, the issue has to do with a bug in the TinyMCE Directive. By default there is no priority set. Setting it to a value of 1 or higher fixes it. It seems that the current version of Ui-TinyMCE Directive has this fixed, but the version I pulled down less than a month ago didn't have it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to recreate what you're describing (substituting $http with $timeout) to no avail. Here's my solution and it seems to be working just fine.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <textarea ui-tinymce="" class="form-control" ng-model="someHtml"></textarea>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('testTinymceApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.someHtml = '<h1>HELLO THERE</h1>'
    }, 7000);

    // This does the same thing with an XHR request instead of timeout
    // $http.get('/some/data/').success(function(result) {
    //   $scope.someHtml = '<h1>HELLO THERE</h1>'
    // });
  });
```

I thought maybe you could compare with your own application? I know for a fact that this works  with XHR requests. I'm building a CMS at work that uses what I assume is an identical workflow.

The `someHtml` attribute in this snippet will also be valid HTML under the covers, so sending it back in a POST request should be extremely easy.

If this is not sufficient, please provide further explanation.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me. Basically it seems that if `$scope.tinymceMOdel = 'test';` is defined anywhere other than the root level of the controller it doesn't work. 

If I copy and paste your code into my controller (and update the model name of course) it still doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: I would have to know more about your application at this point. Are you sure that you're setting the `ng-model` attribute on your textarea?

Comment: Yes of course. Again I can display content in TinyMCE no problem. However if I set the ng-model inside of a callback (or $timeout) TinyMCE ignores the changes.

Here's a snippet Markup: `<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinyMCEModel"></textarea>` Controller:  `$scope.apiCall = Api.query(function(){$scope.tinyMCEModel = 'test' });`

Comment: Interesting... what's your version of AngularJS, TinyMCE, and Angular UI TinyMCE?

Comment: Figured it out, the issue has to do with a bug in the TinyMCE Directive. By default there is no priority set. Setting it to a value of 1 or higher fixes it.

Comment: Interesting. I've never come across that problem before.